# Android unzip database file from assets folder

Tags: android, zip, assets

I am building the app which i want to unzip the database file from assets. But i am getting this error`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/kjv.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

I am using this code for unzip the file,

```
public void unzip(String _zipFile, String _targetLocation) {

    //create target location folder if not exist
    dirChecker(_targetLocation);

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            //create dir if required while unzipping
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_targetLocation + ze.getName());
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }

        }
        zin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e + "");
    }
}

private void dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(dir);
    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

And call using this,

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/kjv.zip");
    inputPath = path.toString();

    ZipManager zipManager = new ZipManager();
    zipManager.unzip(inputPath, outputPath);
```

I tried, but it was error every time. Can't understand what is the problem. If you have alternative solution then please suggest me. Help me. Thank you.

Comment: try this: <br>
Uri path = Uri.parse(getApplicationContext().getAssets() + "kjv.zip");

Comment: Add zip file at root in asset folder or inside any other folder ?

Comment: yes i added file inside the assets folder...

Comment: did u get this working ?